# Setting an auto increment value starting from a certain value T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, auto-increment

I have an empty column `WHID` in my table. I need to update this column with an auto values, where the 1st value will equal 17

So, I expect the result:

```
WHID:
17
18
19
20
21
22
....
etc.
```

My code is:

```
DECLARE @IncrementValue int
SET @IncrementValue = 17

UPDATE ClientEpisode 
SET [WHID] = @IncrementValue + 1
```

I get a result of 18 in all rows (which is not what I need).

What do I write in `[WHID] = ....`   or how to modify my code in order to get my expected result?

Comment: An SQL `update` statement without a `where` clause will update every record in the table. You'll need a while loop to update records 1 at a time with the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `identity` constraint since you build your table as

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (WHID INT IDENTITY(17,1))
```

here you need to drop the existing column & create new column with `identity` Constraint

```
Alter tableName Drop Column WHID
```

then create column with a new constraint

```
Alter tableName Add WHID Int Identity(17, 1) Go
```

Comment: @ Osama Abu Baker
My table has many other fields and has been already created
I need to update the new field in an existing table ....

Comment: Iif you don't care which rows get which values you could drop that column and add it as an identity `alter TABLE MyTable  drop column WHID` `alter TABLE MyTable  add WHID INT IDENTITY(17,1)`

Comment: @Hell-1931 Note that identity columns may leave gaps, e.g. if an `insert` is rolled back. Deleting rows will also leave gaps.